# SpriteKit scene editor

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

In my `GameScene.sks` file, I have the player with the GameScene as the parent and a `SKLabelNode` as the child of the player. Within the `GameScene.sks` file, I have the text as 0 and the following code within `GameScene.swift` file

```
playerHealthLbl = childNode(withName: "playerHealthLbl") as? SKLabelNode
playerHealthLbl?.text = String(200)
```

The issue here is that whenever I build and run my project, the .`SKLableNode.text` is still equal to 0 instead of 200. I made sure that the name in `GameScene.sks` file is the same as `GameScene.swift` file. 
Also, if I switch the `SKLabelNode`'s parent to the scene itself, then the text changes to 200. Any ideas why? Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the label is a child of player not self

`childNode(withName: "playerHealthLbl")` is the same as `self.childNode(withName: "playerHealthLbl")`

and self is the scene (in this instance), and scene doesn't have a child named 
"playerHealthLbl"

so you want to do `player.childNode(withName: "playerHealthLbl")`

or `childNode(withName: "//playerHealthLbl")` which transverses through all children regardless of layer

Comment: Thanks man! I was so used to hardcoding all the time that something this simple became so difficult -.-

Comment: been there...many times...it's easy to get so focused that it becomes hard to see the simple problems. glad to help

Comment: Been at it for like an hour or so. Guess that's what happens for trying to do it the easy way.

Comment: stick with it, I used to be frustrated with Scene editor as well, but now i can't imagine going back to hard coding

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for both help and advice.